# zend form multicheckboxes naming

Tags: php, zend-framework

how do i have to nest multicheckboxes so that they are named like this 'foo[]['bar']' .

i've used subforms but they give me naming like this 'foo[bar][]'.

my code:

> $sub = new Zend_Form_SubForm('sub');
>
> $wish = new Zend_Form_Element_MultiCheckbox('bar');
>
> $wish
>
> ```
> ->setMultiOptions($education_direction->getAll())
> ->setLabel('Wish')    
> ->setRequired(true);
> ```
>
> $sub->addElements(array(
>       $wish
>   ));
>
> $this->addSubForm($sub, 'foo');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you are looking for "belongsTo" Option for Zend Form Elements.

If you need somethinge like:

Try:

```
$this->addElement(
         'text', 'field1', 
            array(
             'label'     => 'field',
             'belongsTo' => 'foo'
        ));
```

Comment: awesome. i've set 'belongsTo' => 'foo[]' and i got the field name as 'foo[]['field1]'. works like a charm. thank you very much :)